# Error:Artifact 'name:jar': java.lang.OutOfMemoryError for IntelliJ

Tags: plugins, out-of-memory, minecraft, intellij-14, artifact

Before I start, just to clarify some things (not trying to sound rude) I have looked around online and I understand that there are some solutions to the problem I am about to explain, however I have tried atleast 5 or 6 and they don't seem to be doing the trick unfortunately :( Some of the solutions that don't work for me include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359868/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581501/how-can-i-give-the-intellij-compiler-more-heap-space).

Essentially, I am creating a Spigot plugin that is lightweight (i.e. Only a few classes, nothing out of the norm or anything that would be intensive. In fact, the compiled .jar is only 44MB at this point in time)

However, my IDE of choice is IntelliJ. When I compile the plugin to output the .jar file, the method I use (which I believe is the best way to do so) is to go to **Build > Build Artifacts > Build** This is where the problem entails. In the messages tab of IntelliJ, it reports `Error:Artifact 'name:jar': java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` Please note that I have replaced my plugin name for "name:jar" for this question as you can see above.

- My Build process heap size is set to "1500mb"
- My VM options for Importer is set to "-Xmx512m"
- My PC has 8192mb of RAM (it uses nowhere near that amount at any
  time)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: 44 MB for a plugin isn't lightweight at all. That's ten times the size of big plugins like dynmap. Seems you included a lot of external resources in your jar.

Comment: The only thing I have is Spigot 1.13

Comment: That doesn't belong in the jar, though.

Comment: I've fixed the issue now. I decided to remake my project including maven as it's easier to manage dependencies in the long term.